# Отсутствует привязанный язык подсветки для метки [kotlin]

Tags: дефект, метки, подсветка-синтаксиса

Из-за этого не подсвечиваются ключевые слова языка (в частности, `fun`, `open`):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

(пример взят из [этого вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1147963/1365))

Если указать явно `kotlin` или `lang-kotlin`, то подсветка работает:

```kotlin
fun main()
{
    println(A() == B())
}

open class A
open class B
```

Comment: это намек на то, что kotlin - не нужен :)

Comment: Написал [коммент](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/331436/kotlin-highlighting#comment1172708_344954) на MSE в ответе, где разрешили подсветку для kotlin (как предполагалось, глобально, если я правильно понял). Может пропишут, если снизойдут до неанглоязычных сайтов.

Comment: [Похоже](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/385705/3240681), что модераторы должны иметь возможность изменять подсветку по умолчанию для меток.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, да, вроде можно было.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Подсветку включили](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/331436/kotlin-highlighting/344954?noredirect=1#comment1172716_344954). Международные модераторы молодцы :)

Главное, вовремя подпнуть.